# Problem with SQL Stored Function, Return Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION salarystatus(employee_id integer) RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    
   DECLARE isalary DECIMAL(8,2);
   DECLARE istatus varchar(25);
   
        SELECT salary INTO isalary 
        FROM employees
        WHERE employee_id = salarystatus.employee_id;
        
    IF (isalary < 50000) then
        SET istatus = 'low income';
    ELSEIF (50000 <= isalary < 80000) then
        SET istatus = 'medium income';
    ELSE 
        SET istatus = 'high income';
    ENDIF
    
    RETURN istatus
    
END
```

Returning this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN istatus
>
> END' at line 20

This this query looks correct, what's the syntax error here?

Comment: Try putting a `delimiter statement before the the `CREATE` . . . `DELIMITER $$`.

Comment: End if not endif and every statement needs to be terminated

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I wrote ENDIF instead of "END IF"

Also add this in the end.

$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: You have way more problems in your code, i think mine answer covers most off them.

Answer (score 0):

> End if not endif and every statement needs to be terminated

P.Salmon already commented while i was making a answer out off it.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION
 # best to prefix with in_ so MySQL and you cant mix it up with existing columns
 salarystatus (in_employee_id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
BEGIN
  DECLARE isalary DECIMAL(8,2) DEFAULT NULL; # <- best to have a default value
  DECLARE istatus varchar(25)  DEFAULT NULL; # <- best to have a default value

  SELECT salary
  INTO isalary 
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = in_employee_id.employee_id; #<- use the function in param

  IF (isalary < 50000) then
    SET istatus = 'low income';
  ELSEIF (50000 <= isalary < 80000) then
    SET istatus = 'medium income';
  ELSE 
    SET istatus = 'high income';
  END IF; # <- semicon (;) missing in your query also ENDIF isnt valid syntax. 

  RETURN istatus;
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Also i remove `DETERMINISTIC` because it's not really needed.